# What is the use of CLK125 on Ethernet PHY?

Tags: ethernet, zynq

We are working on a KSZ9031 Ethernet PHY with a Zynq 7020.
I don't know where connect the CLK125 signal on a Zynq 7020.
What is the use of this signal ?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: possibly 125MHz  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to connect the CLK125 line to anything on the Zynq7020.  We have had success in our implementation just leaving it as a no-connect on the PHY.

See also Sheet 6 of the Zedboard Schematics where they do something similar. [Zedboard Schematics](http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/ZedBoard_RevD.2_Schematic_130516.pdf)